# Adding New customize widget for maximo spatial to map toolbar

Tags: javascript, widget, websphere, maximo

I am trying to add a new customized widget to the map toolbar in maximo spatial (maximo version 7.6.0.9). I tried following the steps i found in this link: http://www.blogjava.net/cpegtop/articles/372769.html

However, the customized widget do not appear on the map toolbar. If anyone has any experience in adding a new customized widget to the map tool bar in maximo spatial, appreciate some help on this.

Thank you.

Comment: If you post in the [Maximo Spatial Community](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/communities/community-home?CommunityKey=a00221b0-8301-4644-8dbe-0d26b988ea0b), you might find someone who can point you to the old Spatial customization wiki articles.

Comment: For example, here's an old PDF I saved: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D7PFPGvDuM2hylBPB0rBS1ZkodhXLEl5/view?usp=sharing. There were lots of other helpful wikis on the old DevWorks site. But that site was taken down.

Comment: @User1973 Thank you so much, i will take a look at the pdf. 
In the mean time i will also post in the maximo spatial community to try my luck too. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

The instructions from the PDF provided by @User1973 works. To insert a customized widget to maximo spatial, you will have to edit the spatial.json file in (<MAXIMO_ROOT>\applications\maximo\maximouiweb\webmodule\webclient\javascript\ibm\tivoli\fwm\mxmap\toolbar\ext) to include your new tool name

You will also need to edit the mxmap.CSS file in <MAXIMO_ROOT>\applications\maximo\maximouiweb\webmodule\webclient\skins<STYLE>\css
to include the icon for your new tool.